# How do I log the total memory allocated in Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, memory-management

I see [malloc_allocated_size](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/GC.html#method-c-malloc_allocated_size) which might be the total amount of memory.  However:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
$ ruby -e 'puts GC::malloc_allocated_size'
-e:1:in `<main>': undefined method `malloc_allocated_size'
  for GC:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Is malloc_allocated_size the right method to get total memory allocated?  How do I call it?

Comment: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3124687 might be able to help. I'm not sure.

Comment: I found that as well.  It didn't help me.